# jQuery Countdown to Delivery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

The latest dispatch for the shop is 5pm monday to friday. I've figured how to create something that shows the same for every day using the standard JS data object and it's very basic but does not do what I need it to do.

Any ideas? Should I go the route of how the code below looks or try using something like moment.js and do it that way?

```
setInterval(function () {

    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getYear();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var day = now.getDay();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var end;

    if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {

        // Not the weekend
        if (hour < 17) { 
            // Before 5 not on weekends
            // end = 5 today
            end = new Date(year, month, day, 17, 0, 0, 0);  
            console.log('before 5');
        } else if (hour >= 17 && day == 5) {
            // After 5 on friday. Set for monday
            // end = 5 monday
            //end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day + 1, 17, 0, 0, 0); 
            console.log('after 5 on friday');
        } else {
            // After 5 monday-thursday
            // end = 5 tomorrow
            console.log('after 5 not on friday');
            end = new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 0, 0, 0); 
        }

    } else {
        // Weekend
        // end = next monday
        console.log('Shipped monday');
    }

    var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var diff = new Date(timeleft);

    console.log("Order now and we ship your order in: " + diff.getHours() + "h " + diff.getMinutes() + "Min " + diff.getSeconds() + "Sec");    

}, 1000);
```

I need it to show after 5PM the count down to the next day delivery time. Friday after 5PM show the Monday delivery time, the same goes for Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: I would suggest you retrieve a UTC date from the server as getting the date from the client is not reliable for business-critical operations. With your current logic someone could quite easily change their system date and then place a next-day delivery at 11:59PM.

Comment: Also to set to 17, you just need to do `someDate.setHours(17,0,0,0)` and pad with `function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2) }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is only informational, it don't do much more than that.

Comment: @mplungjan Is this how I change the date then? I had tried to set the day and times but it wasn't working. I'll edit the question and show you what I mean

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```js
setInterval(function () {  
    var now = new Date();    
    var missedTodaysDelivery = now.getHours() >= 17 ? 1 : 0;
    var end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + missedTodaysDelivery, 17, 0, 0, 0);

    var lastCall = new Date(end);
    lastCall.setDate(now.getDate() + (5 - now.getDay()));

    if (now > lastCall) {
        end = new Date(lastCall);
        end.setDate(end.getDate() + 3);
    }

    var diff = new Date( end - now );
    diff.setTime( diff.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * diff.getTimezoneOffset() );

    var result = "Order now and we ship your order in: ";
    result += diff.getDate() - 1 == 0 ? "" : diff.getDate() - 1 + "days ";
    result += diff.getHours() == 0 ? "" : diff.getHours() + "h ";
    result += diff.getMinutes() == 0 ? "" : diff.getMinutes() + "Min ";
    result += diff.getSeconds() + "Sec ";

    document.body.innerHTML = result;    
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2)}
function getHHMMSS(ms) {
  var seconds = parseInt(ms / 1000) % 60 ;
  var minutes = parseInt(ms / (1000*60)) % 60;
  var hours   = parseInt(ms / (1000*60*60)) % 24;
  console.log(parseInt(ms / 1000) % 60 )
  var str = pad(hours)+" hour"+(hours==1?"":"s")+" "+
    pad(minutes)+" minute"+(minutes==1?"":"s")+" "+
    pad(seconds)+" second"+(seconds==1?"":"s");
  return str;
}

setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date(); // server time
    var end = new Date(now.getTime());
    var hour = now.getHours()+now.getMinutes()/60;
    if (hour>17) end.setDate(end.getDate()+1); // too late today
    var day = end.getDay();
    end.setHours(17,0,0,0); 
    if (!(day>=1 && day<=5)) { // weekend
      end.setDate(end.getDate()+(day==0?1:2)); // add one on sunday 2 on saturday
    }
    var diff = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    document.getElementById("open").innerHTML="Order now and we ship your order in: " + 
      getHHMMSS(diff) +"<br/>("+new Date(now.getTime()+diff)+")";
},500);
```

```html
<span id="open"></span>
```